# XQuery: Como puedo devolver multiples valores en return formateado. No entiendo porque me lo devuelve concatenado

Tags: xml, sql, xpath

Recientemente estoy aprendiendo XQuery, he intenado el siguiente ejercicio:

> Queremos mostrar por cada alumno del instituto (institut.xml) su
>   nombre y las asignaturas que cursa, además del total de asignaturas,
>   ordenado por número de asignaturas que cursa el alumno, en el
>   siguiente formato para cada alumno :

```
<alumne>
  <nom>Filomeno Garcia</nom>
  <credits>
    <credit>Programació</credit>
    <credit>Xarxes Locals</credit>
    <total>2</total>
  </credits>
</alumne>
```

Lo he intentado con

```
for $x in doc("institut")/persones/alumne order by count($x/credits/assignatura) return <alumne>{$x/nom}<credits><credit>{data($x/credits/assignatura)}</credit><total>{count($x/credits/assignatura)}</total></credits></alumne>
```

usando BaseX 9.0 me devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
<alumne>
  <nom>Marcelinu Paivinu</nom>
  <credits>
    <credit>Xarxes Locals</credit>
    <total>1</total>
  </credits>
</alumne>
<alumne>
  <nom>Eustaquio Pons</nom>
  <credits>
    <credit>XML</credit>
    <total>1</total>
  </credits>
</alumne>
<alumne>
  <nom>Pere Nou</nom>
  <credits>
    <credit>Programació</credit>
    <total>1</total>
  </credits>
</alumne>
<alumne>
  <nom>Federicu Pi</nom>
  <credits>
    <credit>XML Xarxes Locals</credit>
    <total>2</total>
  </credits>
</alumne>
<alumne>
  <nom>Filomeno Garcia</nom>
  <credits>
    <credit>Programació Xarxes Locals</credit>
    <total>2</total>
  </credits>
</alumne>
<alumne>
  <nom>Tomeu Bonys</nom>
  <credits>
    <credit>XML Programació</credit>
    <total>2</total>
  </credits>
</alumne>
<alumne>
  <nom>Bernat Garengou</nom>
  <credits>
    <credit>XML Xarxes Locals</credit>
    <total>2</total>
  </credits>
</alumne>
<alumne>
  <nom>Bill Garcia</nom>
  <credits>
    <credit>XML Programació Xarxes Locals</credit>
    <total>3</total>
  </credits>
</alumne>
```

**Como se puede apreciar, he cambiado el nombre 'assignatura' por 'credit' usando el formato del return, pero en vez de devolverme múltiples 'credit' lo concatena todo en uno.**

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Cito el archivo xml original:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persones>
  <professor>
       <nom>Pere Garcia</nom>
        <assignatura>XML</assignatura>
  </professor>
  <professor>
       <nom>Joan Perdut</nom>
       <assignatura>Xarxes Locals</assignatura>
  </professor>
  <professor>
       <nom>Johannes Wirth</nom>
       <assignatura>Programació</assignatura>
  </professor>
  <alumne>
    <nom>Federicu Pi</nom>
    <poblacio>Barcelona</poblacio>
    <any>2010</any>
    <credits>
      <assignatura>XML</assignatura>
      <assignatura>Xarxes Locals</assignatura>
    </credits>
  </alumne>
  <alumne>
    <nom>Marcelinu Paivinu</nom>
    <poblacio>L'Hospitalet</poblacio>
    <any>2010</any>
    <credits>
      <assignatura>Xarxes Locals</assignatura>
    </credits>
  </alumne>
  <alumne>
    <nom>Filomeno Garcia</nom>
    <poblacio>Barcelona</poblacio>
    <any>2010</any>
    <credits>
      <assignatura>Programació</assignatura>
      <assignatura>Xarxes Locals</assignatura>
    </credits>
  </alumne>
  <alumne>
    <nom>Eustaquio Pons</nom>
    <poblacio>Badalona</poblacio>
    <any>2009</any>
    <credits>
      <assignatura>XML</assignatura>
    </credits>
  </alumne>
  <alumne>
    <nom>Tomeu Bonys</nom>
    <poblacio>Barcelona</poblacio>
    <any>2009</any>
    <credits>
      <assignatura>XML</assignatura>
      <assignatura>Programació</assignatura>
    </credits>
  </alumne>
  <alumne>
    <nom>Bernat Garengou</nom>
    <poblacio>L'Hospitalet</poblacio>
    <any>2010</any>
    <credits>
      <assignatura>XML</assignatura>
      <assignatura>Xarxes Locals</assignatura>
    </credits>
  </alumne>
  <alumne>
    <nom>Pere Nou</nom>
    <poblacio>Badalona</poblacio>
    <any>2010</any>
    <credits>
      <assignatura>Programació</assignatura>
    </credits>
  </alumne>
  <alumne>
    <nom>Bill Garcia</nom>
    <any>2010</any>
    <credits>
      <assignatura>XML</assignatura>
      <assignatura>Programació</assignatura>
      <assignatura>Xarxes Locals</assignatura>
    </credits>
  </alumne>
</persones>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto con un **for anidado:** *(no sabia que se podian anidar al realizar la pregunta)*

```
for $alumne in doc("institut")/persones/alumne
let $total := count($alumne/credits/assignatura)
order by $total
return <alumne>

<nom>{data($alumne/nom)}</nom>
<credits> {

               for $a in $alumne/credits/assignatura
               return <credit>{data($a)}</credit>
          }
<total>
{$total}
</total>

</credits>
</alumne>
```